# Webpack output files

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-frontend

I'm using webpack for development. It runs fine and I can see the output in my browser using the dev-server.
However, now I'd like to take the output files and move them to a remote, except I can't find them.

The config is as follows:

```
entry: './index.js',
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:8090/assets'
  },
```

But the assets folder isn't created as far as I can see. What is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run this config with the `webpack` command not with the `webpack-dev-server` command, dev-server doesn't create this files on your harddrive, it keeps them in memory.